# Table cell not displaying Image when populated from JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, view

**Question background:**

I'm developing a simple table 'Cart'. I'm passing a populated ViewBag object (that contains a List of 'CartItem' objects) from the Controller to its associated Cart View.

**The code:**

The HTML table layout in the View:

```
<table id="Table1" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><b>Item</b></td>
        <td><b>Brand</b></td>
        <td><b>Unit Price</b></td>
        <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JQuery that populates the table rows from the passed ViewBag list:

```
@foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{
    <script>

    var cartImage = '@cartItem.CartItemImage';
    var cartItemName = '@cartItem.CartItemName';
    var cartBrand = '@cartItem.CartItemBrand';
    var cartItemPrice = '@cartItem.CartItemPrice';
    var cartItemCartItemQty = '@cartItem.CartItemQty';

    AddRows(cartImage, cartItemName, cartBrand, cartItemPrice, cartItemCartItemQty)

    </script>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

var AddRows = function (productImage, productName, productBrand, productPrice, productQty) {

    var image = '<img src="~/Images/' + productImage + '" class="productCartImage"/>';

    var $html = $('<tr>' +
    '<td>' + image + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + productName + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + productBrand + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + productPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + productQty + '</td>' +
    '</tr>');

    $('#Table1 > tbody:last').append($html);
};
</script>
```

**The issue:**

Currently the above JQuery populates the table as shown:

[image]

Everything populates correctly except as shown the image is not displaying.

Inspecting the element in Chrome. **Note I have ensured that the image exists in the Images folder** If I put the `img src` outside of the JQuery function the image displays. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: This address "~/Images/..." seems no good. Is it correct? Is it accessible?

Comment: @ChrisBenseler I actually solved this after posting the question but you helped me. It was the fact i added the '~'. After this off it worked. Please put this as an answer and i'll mark it correctly.